# Combined div elements combined with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I got an html page like this:

```
<div id="foo">
  first
  <div>
    second
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, I want to use the jQuery click method but should only work when clicking `first`, not `second`. But if doing something like

```
$("#foo").click(function() { do things });
```

If I click inside the `second`, its like clicking also on the `first` and the above function will run. Can I avoid this? So, clicking in `second`, won't run the above function of the `first`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can!

```
$("#foo div.second").click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

That will stop propagation to elements "above" in the tree.

Comment: Or rather `$("#foo div") with your example HTML.

Comment: Minor note: @Jared's link should be viewed with Firebug/Console enabled.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#foo').click(function(e) {
    // Do your snazzy stuff.
});

$('#foo div').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

= OR =

```
$('#foo').children().click(function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```